# How to delete web modules from virtual server in glass fish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish-3

I developed a web service. When i want to publish it on the server, then i get the following error

```
cannot Deploy TemperatureConverterServiceClientEAR
Deployment Error for module: TemperatureConverterServiceClientEAR: Error occurred
during  deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: WEB0113:
Virtual server [server] already has a web module 
[AndroidBackendAuthentication.war] loaded at [/AndroidBackendAuthentication]; 
therefore web module 
[TemperatureConverterServiceClientEAR#AndroidBackendAuthentication.war] cannot be 
loaded at this context path on this virtual server. . Please see server.log for 
more details
```

I went to directory `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps` and delete all the files. I also went to 
[image]

Then i click on the server. In the `default Web module` option i have following entries

[image]

How can i delete these modules from here. Whenever i tried to deploy webservice i get this message.  How can i get rid of this message?  I also delete the deployed module from the Application option after which this `default Web module` option become empty. But then if i try to deploy any webservice , i get the error. Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

you shold undeploy the old web moudle

use the flow command to do this:

```
./bin/asadmin --port $port undeploy $app
```

`$port` means the "glassfish admin port". when you use `start-domain`  you will see it

`$app` means the name of the old moudle you want to undeploy, you can use `./bin/asadmin --port $port list-applications` commands to see all the web moudles had been deployed to this domain

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found exist:
go into `server/glass fish server (node)/application`. And there You've got app blocked Your work. Just delete it, and ready :)

Comment: Can you please reword your answer to make it more readable? Try using the backtick character to display the menu links with a nice grey background.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I was able to fix it by restarting glassfish. Go to services->Servers. Right click on glassfish and restart. Hope that helps.